# Bind SSL Certificate from KeyVault to webapp using Azure CLI

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-web-app-service, azure-cli

We are currently using the following ARM template to bind the an SSL certificate to a WebApp, but we want to migrate to Azure CLI, but cannot find a way to do this without downloading the certificate.

```
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/certificates",
  "name": "[variables('certificateName')]",
  "apiVersion": "2016-03-01",
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "properties": {
    "keyVaultId": "[resourceId(parameters('existingKeyVaultResourceGroup'), 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults',parameters('existingKeyVaultId'))]",
    "keyVaultSecretName": "[parameters('existingKeyVaultSecretName')]",
    "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverFarms',variables('hostingPlanName'))]"
  }
},
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/hostnameBindings",
  "name": "[concat(variables('webAppName'), '/', variables('hostname'))]",
  "apiVersion": "2016-03-01",
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "properties": {
    "sslState": "SniEnabled",
    "thumbprint": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/certificates', variables('certificateName'))).Thumbprint]"
  },
  "dependsOn": [
    "[concat('Microsoft.Web/certificates/',variables('certificateName'))]"
  ]
}
```

Comment: yeah, I just download the pfx from keyfault and update it as stated below. Allthough I'm using powershell instead of CLI (I don't think the bash stuff will work with cmd)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is sample script on the official [site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/scripts/cli-configure-ssl-certificate), if you don't want to download it, you should have it on your local.

```
#!/bin/bash

fqdn=<replace-with-www.{yourdomain}>
pfxPath=<replace-with-path-to-your-.PFX-file>
pfxPassword=<replace-with-your=.PFX-password>
resourceGroup=myResourceGroup
webappname=mywebapp$RANDOM

# Create a resource group.
az group create --location westeurope --name $resourceGroup

# Create an App Service plan in Basic tier (minimum required by custom domains).
az appservice plan create --name $webappname --resource-group $resourceGroup --sku B1

# Create a web app.
az webapp create --name $webappname --resource-group $resourceGroup \
--plan $webappname

echo "Configure a CNAME record that maps $fqdn to $webappname.azurewebsites.net"
read -p "Press [Enter] key when ready ..."

# Before continuing, go to your DNS configuration UI for your custom domain and 
follow the 
# instructions at https://aka.ms/appservicecustomdns to configure a CNAME record for 
the 
# hostname "www" and point it your web app's default domain name.

# Map your prepared custom domain name to the web app.
az webapp config hostname add --webapp-name $webappname --resource-group 
$resourceGroup \
--hostname $fqdn

# Upload the SSL certificate and get the thumbprint.
thumbprint=$(az webapp config ssl upload --certificate-file $pfxPath \
--certificate-password $pfxPassword --name $webappname --resource-group 
$resourceGroup \
--query thumbprint --output tsv)

# Binds the uploaded SSL certificate to the web app.
az webapp config ssl bind --certificate-thumbprint $thumbprint --ssl-type SNI \
--name $webappname --resource-group $resourceGroup

echo "You can now browse to https://$fqdn"
```

Hope this could help you, if you still have other questions, please let me know.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that example, I was hoping I could remotely bind the certificate without downloading the PFX to the deployment machine.

Comment: @Luuk If so, I suggest you using Azure Key Vault,you could refer to this link.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-purchase-ssl-web-site#start-certificate-order

Comment: Had the same issue and looks like `az webapp config ssl import` might be helpful here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/config/ssl?view=azure-cli-latest#az-webapp-config-ssl-import

Answer (score 0):

TLS/SSL --> Private key certificate --> import key vault certificate

can any one please share arm/script to configure.

Manaully we are apply to do and we need script to perform

[image: image here]

Comment: How can you "click" on that button through Azure CLI?

Comment: I don't know if you figured it out, but I did it through the `az webapp config ssl import` command. Documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/config/ssl?view=azure-cli-latest#az_webapp_config_ssl_import)